# Pandas DataFrame.sort_values() failed conversion of problematic datetime, but only when sorting multiple keys

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Here is a sample of a dataset with a problematic datetime entry:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import os
>>> df = pd.read_hdf(os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/bad_starttime.hdf'), key='data')
>>> df
               starttime               result_time  question_id
0  2014-02-24 18:29:26+00:00 2014-02-24 18:30:03+00:00            4
1  2014-02-24 18:30:13+00:00 2014-02-24 18:30:53+00:00            9
2  2014-02-24 18:31:04+00:00 2014-02-24 18:31:23+00:00            3
3  2014-02-24 18:31:35+00:00 2014-02-24 18:32:01+00:00            6
4  2014-02-24 18:32:11+00:00 2014-02-24 18:34:20+00:00            5
5  9999-05-28 22:06:33+00:00 2014-03-02 04:37:00+00:00            6
6  2014-03-02 04:37:24+00:00 2014-03-02 04:54:27+00:00           11
7  2014-03-02 04:53:12+00:00 2014-03-02 04:54:11+00:00            8
```

This dataframe can be sorted by the 'starttime' key, by itself, tout de suite:

```
>>> df.sort_values('starttime')
                   starttime               result_time  question_id
0  2014-02-24 18:29:26+00:00 2014-02-24 18:30:03+00:00            4
1  2014-02-24 18:30:13+00:00 2014-02-24 18:30:53+00:00            9
2  2014-02-24 18:31:04+00:00 2014-02-24 18:31:23+00:00            3
3  2014-02-24 18:31:35+00:00 2014-02-24 18:32:01+00:00            6
4  2014-02-24 18:32:11+00:00 2014-02-24 18:34:20+00:00            5
6  2014-03-02 04:37:24+00:00 2014-03-02 04:54:27+00:00           11
7  2014-03-02 04:53:12+00:00 2014-03-02 04:54:11+00:00            8
5  9999-05-28 22:06:33+00:00 2014-03-02 04:37:00+00:00            6
```

However, things go nutty when sorting on multiple keys (lightly edited). Note that it doesn't matter what the second key is; this happens with `['starttime','question_id']` as well as the keys shown:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['starttime','result_time'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 409, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1595, in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas/tslib.c:29625)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1334, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:25690)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1562, in pandas.tslib._check_dts_bounds (pandas/tslib.c:29245)
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-05-28 22:06:33

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3145, in sort_values
    na_position=na_position)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 4138, in _lexsort_indexer
    c = Categorical(key, ordered=True)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 301, in __init__
    categories = self._validate_categories(categories)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 495, in _validate_categories
    categories = Index(categories, dtype=dtype)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 253, in __new__
    **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/index.py", line 363, in __new__
    subarr = tools._to_datetime(data, box=False, utc=True)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 427, in _to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 412, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 398, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2134, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:41972)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2280, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:40843)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2163, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:38742)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1334, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:25690)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1562, in pandas.tslib._check_dts_bounds (pandas/tslib.c:29245)
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-05-28 22:06:33
```

Note that supplying the single column 'starttime' as a list ['starttime',] works correctly; it appears the problem lies in using the column with out of bounds data together with other columns.

Question 1: is this a bug? Or is it the expected result? If the latter, what is the cause? 
Question 2: is there a clean workaround that keeps the data as date/time? Perhaps calling sort_values() in sequence (albeit at the cost of multiple function calls)?

I'm happy to provide the hdf file if needed.

This was using pandas 0.18.1 and python 3.5.2.

EDIT: here are the datatypes of the problematic column.

```
>>> df.starttime.apply(lambda x: type(x))
0    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
2    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
3    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
4    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
5    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
6    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
7    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
Name: starttime, dtype: object
>>> df.starttime.dtype
dtype('O')
```

EDIT 2:
Output of df.info():

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 3 columns):
starttime      8 non-null object
result_time    8 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
question_id    8 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes
```

Output of df0.info() (Ted's version, below):

```
>>> df0.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9999 entries, 0 to 9998
Data columns (total 3 columns):
col           9999 non-null float64
resulttime    9999 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
starttime     9999 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 234.4+ KB
```

Comment: What are the data types of starttime and resulttime? And can you sort by just resulttime by itself. Can you take the min and max of resulttime? Looks like you have a year that is 9999 which is far from the max timestamp possible which is something like year 2300, so it can't sort it.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, long time lurker, short time poster. 1. `starttime` is a `datetime.datetime` -- I've added code showing that. 2. `result_time` is a pandas Timestamp; the data can be sorted with either `result_time` or `['result_time','question_id']` just fine, presumably because the data are sane. 3. No, the `starttime` column being year 9999 is not the (immediate) problem -- `sort_values()` seems to work fine when that is the only sort key.

Comment: It looks like when you sort with both columns, pandas tries to convert starttime which is datetime to a pandas timestamp. Pandas timestamps have nanosecond precision and because of that have a bound from the years 16xx to 22xx. Year 9999 is far out of bounds of this region. Convert resulttime to a datetime object and it should sort fine. You will lose nanosecond precision though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting issue appears to be a problem with pandas 0.18.1, not with 0.19.1.

```
~$ cat testdate.py 
import datetime
import pandas as pd 
import pkg_resources as pr
print('pandas', pr.get_distribution('pandas').version)

dates = pd.Series([datetime.datetime(9999,5,28),
                   datetime.datetime(2017,1,15)]) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates,'n':0})

try:
    df.sort_values(['dates','n'])
    print('sorting worked')
except pd.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: 
    print('sorting failed')
~$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
~$ python testdate.py 
pandas 0.19.1
sorting worked
~$ activate-venv 
(venv) ~$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
(venv) ~$ python testdate.py 
pandas 0.18.1
sorting failed
```

However, the underlying issue of being unable to convert a UTC-aware out-of-bounds `datetime` still obtains:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime(9999,1,1,0,0,0,0,datetime.timezone.utc))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 410, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1747, in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas/tslib.c:32261)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1467, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:27811)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1721, in pandas.tslib._check_dts_bounds (pandas/tslib.c:31881)
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-01-01 00:00:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 430, in to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 413, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 401, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2302, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:45739)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2348, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:42371)
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

It is still a problem if one sets `utc=True`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime(9999,1,1,0,0,0,0,datetime.timezone.utc), utc=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 410, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1747, in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas/tslib.c:32261)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1467, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:27811)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1721, in pandas.tslib._check_dts_bounds (pandas/tslib.c:31881)
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-01-01 00:00:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 430, in to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 413, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 401, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2302, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:45739)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2485, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:44633)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2338, in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:42170)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1467, in pandas.tslib.convert_to_tsobject (pandas/tslib.c:27811)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1721, in pandas.tslib._check_dts_bounds (pandas/tslib.c:31881)
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-01-01 00:00:00
```

This can be avoided by ignoring the timezone field in the underlying data, which in my case isn't important. Nevertheless, I'll be spending the remainder of the year Googling whether Pandas should behave better in this case, and opening a bug report if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to python datetime. `df['resulttime'] = df['resulttime'].dt.to_pydatetime()`

then sort `df.sort_values(['starttime','resulttime'])`

I also can't reproduce this error with the following

```
d = [datetime.datetime(year=year, month = 5, day=9) for year in range(1, 10000)]
d1 = pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=9999, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime':d, 'resulttime':d1, 'col':np.ones(9999)})
df.sort_values(['starttime', 'resulttime'])
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this occurs regardless which of the other two columns I sort by. Moreover, it occurs even when attempting to coerce the other time column as per your suggestion. I have edited the question to reflect these observations.

Comment: Can you check the edited code above to see if the bottom 4 lines of code works for you? And can you paste the results of `df.info()` here.

Comment: Aha! I think we've made some progress, Ted. When I run your bottom-4 lines, I get 'pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-05-09 00:00:00'. What versions of pandas, python and numpy are you running?

Comment: pandas 0.19.1 and numpy 1.11.2. Try upgrading

Comment: Annoyingly, with pandas 0.19.1 (no difference numpy 1.11.0 and 1.11.2) I get a different error, again when sorting with the problematic key 'starttime' and any other key: `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`. However, your bottom-4 lines now work. Are you using Python 3?